# Error on using javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey annotation in code using Jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: jpa, jboss6.x

I am using `javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey` in my code. The project is working fine using WildFly server, but when I use Jboss EAP 6.1, it gives below error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
>               org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2884)
>               org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:3051)
>               org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1839)
>               org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
>               org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)

When I further investigated the issue, I found that JBoss Library does not support Join columns.

However, my project library supports Join column and I intent to use these library in my code. But Jboos libraries seem to be overriding the libraries in the class path.

I tried below code in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<exclusions>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javaee.api"/> 
</exclusions>
```

But I am getting below error

> 11:19:55,195 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."myappl.war".PARSE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."myappl.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to
>   process phase PARSE of deployment "myappl.war" Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWS021001: Unexpected element
>   parsing handlers: handler-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is that EAP 6.3.x is based on the Java EE 6 specification and JPA 2.0 is part of this specification. The most recent versions of Hibernate (4.3.x) bring with version 2.1 of JPA, which is part of the Java EE 7 specification. Theoretically, to solve the problem, it was enough to exclude 'org.hibernate' modules and 'javax.persistence' in jboss-deployment-structure.xml file, but it does not solve the problem. According to Red Hat, this is a BUG.

**1)** A solution is to use the version of Hibernate present in the distribution of EAP 6.3.x. Resolve, but an application can not be held to versions of a server libraries.

**2)** Another solution is to change the version of JPA 2.0 to 2.1 directly in the distribution, located in \JBOSS_DIST\modules\system\layers\base\javax\persistence\api\main. Also resolves, but this solution is not acceptable, since the applications using the Hibernate version 6.3.x present in the EAP may be affected.

**3)** We could would be to follow the steps in this address http://mariemjabloun.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/use-jboss-jpa-21-and-hibernate-43-on.html, but particularly found a solution very laborious.

**4)** Finally, after numerous searches and attempts, found a reasonable solution to work around the problem, at the very site of RedHat: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/404223. I believe in future versions of EAP, it should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss EAP 6.x is [compliant](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) with JPA 2.0 API while [javax.persistence.ForeignKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html) has been added in JPA 2.1.

In order to make it work you need to integrate it manually. A possible workaround can be found [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209)