# JPA / Hibernate java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

**Error message**

> Oct 20, 2015 10:56:33 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO:
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect Oct
>   20, 2015 10:56:33 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder
>   useContextualLobCreation INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB
>   creation as createClob() method threw error :
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

I know that are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588860/error-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkeyljavax-persistence-foreignkey-wi) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550463/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkey) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204113/error-on-using-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkey-annotation-in-code-using) [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062271/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkeyljavax-per), but as stated on most of them they request to make sure that I am using hibernate 4.3+ and JPA2.1+. And I believe that I am using both of them:

Here is my **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="web" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/web"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgresUser"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name" value="web" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>edu.utfpr</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjetoWeb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>ProjetoWeb</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.torpedoquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.torpedoquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Finally here is one example of a BarEntity

```
@Entity
public class BarEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Foo foo;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String bar;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String foobar;
}
```

**What can I do to deploy this?**

I am sorry for not being able to reduce the pom.xml / persistence.xml into more generic, as I am not sure where is the error.

Comment: You have an earlier version of the JPA API in your CLASSPATH (that doesn't have that method). That's all there is to say, self evident from the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by both [Zhao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33249470/2188186) and [hermitmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249354/jpa-hibernate-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror/33249470#comment54301143_33249470) this is definitely a dependency problem. But, I believe that it could be hard for someone with little experience to figure what should match / could be wrong.

**So, here is a how to inspect this**

The relevant data in `pom.xml` is:

```
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    (...)
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    (...)
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
```

As stated by the user he got it right that hibernate needs to be 4.3 or higher. However, it should be using the same version of hibernate and jpamodelgen.

Both **hibernate-entitymanager** and **hibernate-jpamodelgen** should have the same number. Be it:

`4.3.1` or `5.0.2`.

Comment: THank you. Changing what you said really solved this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It usually means that the version of the library you are using is not compatible with the one you really depends on. Please check the version of javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey() library or the one who is using this library to make sure you are using the correct version of them.

Comment: How can I check this version ? Is there a println or something that I could do?

Comment: It is the dependencies on your pom.xml file. First you need to find out which library is using javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey() method. Then check which version it required. If you are mis-using the versions, you will get this kind of error at runtime.

Comment: It's definitely a dependency problem. Also look for duplicate dependencies and try to eliminate them. i.e. two different versions of jpa-api, etc.

Comment: I am using Jboss-eap-6.4 how can I prevent jboss to load older version of javax.persistence, I neither use provided nor compile scope in maven dependency